# American pronunciation of Eva Braun?

Tags: pronunciation

I've heard it all kinds of ways, & now I have to pick one for an audiobook I'm narrating. I'm inclined to say EE-vuh BRAWN, but I just checked youtube(the fount of all pronunciation knowledge) & they say EE-vuh BROWN. Then of course the German(I think) would be AY-vuh. Any consensus?

Comment: Wouldn't the German be "Ay-Fuh"?

Comment: The German for _Eva Braun_ (in IPA symbols, /'e:və braun/) would be Ava (like Ava Gardner, long A at the beginning -- maybe that's what you meant by AY-vuh). The last name is Brown, same word, same meaning.  And that's how she's known, so if you pronounce it any other way nobody will recognize it. If you got any other German names in that audiobook you better check with a German speaker.

Comment: I think most in the US would, absent any clues to the contrary, pronounce it EE-vuh BRAWN, as you suggest.  (Though this likely varies by region, based on how much German heritage is present.)  Of course, for a particular real person you should attempt to match the pronunciation that person uses/used, or, for an historical figure with no audio recordings to reference, use a "best guess" based on your knowledge of the person's heritage.

Comment: @JohnLawler This does raise the question of when we should pronounce foreign names (people and places) as they are pronounced in their own language, and when we use some sort of established English convention. No one, for example, would think of pronouncing *Paris* as *Paree* when speaking English, but in Britain we have evolved our own way of pronouncing almost everyone and everywhere.  There is, for example an established convention in Britain that the surname *Jacques* is pronounced *Jakes* in English.

Comment: @WS2 - And then there's the surname "Favre" in the US.

Comment: @HotLicks That is clearly a French name but not a very common one. There are only 161 Favres in the entire UK telephone records. And bear in mind that London is the sixth largest French city!

Comment: @WS2 - It's only of interest because there's a "Bret Favre" in the US who pronounces it "farv".  Which would not be worth noting except that he's a well-known ex (American) football player.  (OTOH, my wife has some friends with that last name and they pronounce it "fav-ray".)

Comment: @HotLicks French would pronounce it 'fav -re', with emphasis on the first syllable, and one of their retreating r sounds, spoken from the back of the mouth. No doubt one of the linguistics people would describe this more professionally.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think perfect consensus exists on this, but for what it's worth:

> Braun, Eva /braʊn, ˈeɪvə/
>   (1910–45) a German Nazi who married Adolf Hitler in 1945 and then killed herself at the same time as he did

(Latest Longman dictionary.)